# How to split long posts in multiple pages in twentysixteen

Tags: pagination

I am using twentysixteen WordPress theme, Whenever i tried to split long post in multiple page by tag  nothing happened. Kindly help me.

Comment: What did you do that didn't work? A common mistake is to put spaces inside the next page tag. Make sure you haven't any spaces in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **<!--nextpage-->** in Text mode of editor. If you add it through Visual editor - WP will escape it to HTML:

```
&lt;!--nextpage--&gt;
```

and display it literally (instead of pagination):

> <!--nextpage-->

So, check your post by switching to Text editor. If nothing isn't displayed at all when you view the post, this may be a plugin issue. Update your theme to the latest version  and disable all plugins temporarily.

Comment: Besides it is possible to show some same text on all naviaged pages for example i have post title, content, then A, B, C, D etc. I want to show post title and content on all the pages and a,b,c,d  on different navigated pages. It is possible?

Comment: AFAIK, you should open a separate thread for your other question.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved the problem. It will help others as well and decrease the stack of unsolved questions. You can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/270140) how to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/270140). Thanks. @PARVINDER